# Trouble with Unclosed element form

Tags: html, forms, error-handling, w3c-validation

I can´t figure out why my form tag doesn´t recognise it´s close, any ideas ?

I have tried changing the divs a couple of times but it just messes up the whole form.

Code: https://codeshare.io/2pypdD

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it had to do with some non-obvious interactions (for me) between the  and several divs.